# Change the color of one point only in a Flot line chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Is there a way to change the color of one point only (the last) in a line plot?
Hhint: The number of points which I use is 4.

Part of current code is the following:

```
var Arr_data = [[]];
... 
var plot1 = {
      series: {            
        lines: {
          show: false,
          fill: 1,  
        },

        splines: {
          show: true,
          tension: 0.4,
          lineWidth: 2,
          fill: 0.1,
        },

        points: {
          radius: 8,
          lineWidth: 1,
          show: true,
          symbol: "circle",
          fillColor: customColorVar
        },
        ...
$.plot($("#chartID"), [ Arr_data ], plot1);
```

Comment: Similar question (same exercise?): https://stackoverflow.com/q/47572394/2610249

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible with the normal options. What you can do is copy only the last data point to a second data series and for that data series use the different color. This should draw over the point from the first data series. If there are problems with this you could go one step further and generate three data series:

- One with all data points for a line,
- one with all data points but the last for the points in the normal color and
- one with only the last data point for the other color.